# Design pattern in Android default DeskClock application

Tags: android, design-patterns

I'm trying to learn android system and was looking into standard (default) DescClock application (I think I've got it from here: http://omapzoom.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/DeskClock.git). Specifically, my question is about classes `Alarm` and `Alarms`. `Alarm` is an implementation of a single alarm, while `Alarms` has various method of working with `Alarm`. All of the methods of `Alarms` are *static*.

Now, the question. Is it a well known design pattern to make a "manager" class with static methods? What are the general benefits of such approach? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, I thought about this possibly being a [Composite pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern), which is typical when you have a class that can be stand-alone or a container of the same type. But, when I read that all of the `Alarms` methods are static, I realized it has nothing to do with a Composite.

The fact that all of the `Alarms` methods are static implies that `Alarms` has no state, and only acts *behaviorally* on the `Alarm` class instances. After looking at the code, it appears as though the `Alarms` class is a hybrid of the [Facade pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) or even a [Visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern), even though its only working on one class.

What the `Alarms` class is doing is effectively encapsulating the details of ***how*** to work on the `Alarm` class, thus simplifying its use for the end-user. I actually like this approach, although one could argue that if its so difficult to use the `Alarm` class that it has to be encapsulated like this, then maybe its design should be refactored.